# How to keep receiving location notications during a phone call

Tags: android, location

I'm a noobie who has written a couple of basic apps and I now writing an app that creates a tracklog based on the location manager system service. I'm looking for advice as to how I should structure my app so that if a phone call is received the users track log (I store the location every 10 seconds) isn't broken / blank for the period of the call. Will the location service continue to call my onLocationChanged method during the phone call? links to examples really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It only depends on structure of your code  Do you collect coordinates directly from your `Activity` and pause it in `onPause()` callback?

Answer (score 0):

After register a LocationListener in Location Manager, when location changed, the code in onLocationChanged method will be executed.This listener will always run even if you quit the application. You must unregister the listener yourself.

When a phone call incoming, your application will stop temporarily and skip to phone call UI. If you don't unregister LocationListener in OnStop(), the code in onLocationChanged will still be executed.

So I think the phone call will not affect your location service. You could make a test yourself.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the unregister locationListener call to the onDestroy method. I still gets location updates during a phone call. :-)